# Why is attribute being inherited across classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm apparently having some trouble learning how to use classes correctly. I expect the following code to loop through a set of files (it does), adding elements to a set as it goes (it does), and starting the set over when it moves to a new file (*it does not*). The way I've hacked at the code below, I would expect it to return an empty set each time for `file.terminals`, because I believe that each set is the unique attribute of a new instance of the class `SrcFile`. Apparently, I am mistaken. What actually happens is that the set of terminals created by the first file persists (and is added to) for all subsequent files in the list, although other attributes (e.g. `file.name`, `file.seqlength()`) change appropriately with the files. Can someone please explain why it works this way and how I can create the behavior that I'm expecting? Thanks in advance for your patience with a beginning programmer's ignorance.

```
class SrcFile:
   terminals = set([])
   def __init__(self, which):
      self.name = which
   def seqlength(self):
      with open(self.name) as file:
         linecounter = 0
         for line in file:
            linecounter += 1
            if linecounter == 3:
               return int(line.split()[0])
               break

class Record(SrcFile):
   def terminal(self):
      record = self.name
   def terminal(self):
      record = self.name
      return record.split()[0]

for f in files:
   file = SrcFile(f)
   print(file.name, file.seqlength(), file.terminals)

   with open(f) as f:
      recordline = re.compile(r"^([A-Z]{5})\s{3}")
      for line in f:
         if recordline.match(line):
            record = Record(line)
            if record.terminal() in file.terminals:
               pass
            else:
               file.terminals.add(record.terminal())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `terminals` within the class declaration, not within the `__init__` function that's executed for every new instance of the class.

Basically, `terminals` is initialized for the whole class, not for each instance of the class:

```
>>> SrcFile.terminals
set([])
```

Notice I ran `SrcFile.terminals`, not `SrcFile().terminals`, which means that `SrcFile` is a reference to the class, not an instance of the class.

You put variables like that inside of the `__init__` function to make them instance-specific:

```
class SrcFile(object):
  def __init__(self, which):
    self.name = which
    self.terminals = set([])
```

Answer (score 3):

By defining `terminals = set([])` in the class itself it is created **once** when the class is defined an not when an instance is created.

To avoid this, remove it and add the following to your `__init__` method:

```
self.terminals = set()
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I really appreciate the patience of this forum with those of us who are just getting started.

Comment: Got it...so much to learn. Accepting first correct answer submitted and signing off.